# How to use Request.Form("id") for this?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a repeater control which displays id's.

```
<repeater id="a" runat ="server">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="bt1" runat="server" PostBackUrl= '<%# "~/Default.aspx"?id=" + Container.DataItem.ToString() %>' /asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

In my default page I am able to access it like this.

Dim foo as String = Request.QueryString("id")

My question- How would I post the data. By post I mean not using query string because I don't want the id to show up in the url? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Postbackurl is infrequently used in asp.net. If you need to post data to a different page, it's useful, but not for simple postbacks.

When you are within a data binding control like a repeater, use the "commandargument" property of the linkbutton. You can then trap the value in the repeater's itemcommand event in the codebehind.

Here is an example:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would that work for a page post back though?

Comment: Clicking the linkbutton will trigger a postback and fire the itemcommand event on the repeater.  Otherwise, if you are using a button or something located outside the repeater, you'll have to traverse the repeater and do a .FindControl("controlID") to find the linkbutton or hidden value.

Comment: the problem is this repeator control is in a user control. I am using it in the default page. Would the approach you mentioned still work?